# Final Fantasy for iphone: increase font size

Tags: ios, final-fantasy

I just downloaded FF (the original) for iphone, having been happy with FF3 for iOS. However, font size, item lists, etc, are insanely and nausea-inducingly small. I find it even hard to see how the character models actually look like. In fact, as is I declare the game unplayable.

Is there any way to make at least the font size and item lists (eg, shops, inventory) larger?  The basic finger swipe doesn't work, and nothing in the config section.

Comment: Any reason this is tagged Bioshock?

Comment: @Batophibia: yes - autocomplete. I had typed ios which SE substituted to Bioshock. :) for good measure, when I then tried "iphone", it was changed to "iOS". Go figure.

Comment: I would assume it is optimized for the iPad because it is a universal app. If there is no option in the settings I wouldn't keep your hopes up for a fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original [Final Fantasy game for iOS](https://itunes.apple.com/au/app/final-fantasy/id354972939?mt=8) is a universal app designed for both the iPhone and iPad. This game has not been optimized for the small iPhone screen, making the text seem very small (However fine on iPad).

As you said, you are happy with the font size on Final Fantasy III.

In the description for Final Fantasy III (on [iTunes](https://itunes.apple.com/au/app/final-fantasy-iii/id424591347?mt=8)) it mentions that it has been optimized for the 4 inch (iPhone) display.

> Optimized for the 4-inch Retina display.

This is why you have no had a problem with this particular game.

There is no mention of optimization for the original Final Fantasy game, therefore making it "unplayable". There is no way to change the font size in this game. If you have an iPad I would play it on that, otherwise there doesn't seem to be a solution to this problem.